# JQuery click function and timeout

Tags: jquery, click, gallery

I built this function to scroll through a gallery. The gallery should scroll to the next image by itself every 6000ms, but if the user clicks on a thumbnail it should go directly to that thumbnail and then reset the timer for 6000ms.

My code is not working because I do not think I got the JQuery retriggereing function right. Not quite sure what I am doing.

```
var timerp = null;

$('.thumbs').click(function() {
         clearTimeout(timerp);
         $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
         $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus');
     }, function gallery() {
        clearTimeout(timerp);
        timerp = setTimeout(function() {
            var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
            $(islide).removeClass('cornerimgfocus');                    
            if(islide[0]==$('.cornerimg:last')[0]) {
            var nextslide =  $('.cornerimg').first();
            }
            else {
            var nextslide = $(islide).next();
            }
             gallery();
        }, 6000);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

By the way, the mouseclick works perfectly it is only the timeout that I have not got correct.

I tried this. Still nothing. The click is still working but the timeout function is not.

```
$('.thumbs').click(function() {
         clearTimeout(timerp);
         $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
         $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus');
         timerp = setTimeout(function() {
         $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).next().click()
         }, 3000)

    });
```

I thought that if I added the .next().click() it would reactivate this click function but it doesn't. How do we achieve this.

Comment: Does neither mouse clicks nor the 6000ms timeout trigger the transition to the next thumbnail?

Comment: Mouse click does perfectly. The timeout does not do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing two functions to the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method, which is not supported. Also, it looks like you want [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) instead of [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), and you're not adding the `cornerimgfocus` class to the next slide when the timer ticks. Try:

```
var timerp = null;

$('.thumbs').click(function() {
    if (timerp) {
        window.clearInterval(timerp);
    }
    $('.cornerimgfocus').removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
    $('#P' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('cornerimgfocus');
    gallery();
});

function gallery()
{
    timerp = window.setInterval(function() {
        var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
        islide.removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
        var nextSlide;
        if (islide[0] == $('.cornerimg:last')[0]) {
            nextslide = $('.cornerimg').first();
        } else {
            nextslide = islide.next();
        }
        nextSlide.addClass('cornerimgfocus');
    }, 6000);
}

gallery();  // Start the animation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to select an element twice :

```
var islide = $('.cornerimgfocus');
$(islide).removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
```

On the second line you could use :

```
islide.removeClass('cornerimgfocus');
```

Don't know if that caused your problem though,

Max

Comment: The problem is with the timeout

Comment: ok, i see. yet, it looks like Frédéric Hamidi found the problem